# How to access file from host directory of docker container?

Tags: docker

I have this part of my python code which iterates through the folder and add file names to the list.

```
base_path = D:/tests/resources

for file in glob.glob(f'{base_path}/eox/data/eur/*.txt'):
    lst.append(file)
```

Now I have the docker images where I assume it should do the same thing after running this docker command.

```
docker run -i --rm -v D:/tests/resources:/tmp/output dockerimg:latest prepare --base_path D:/tests/resources
```

but somehow the list is empty even though `D:/tests/resources` have txt files in it. Is it because the volume is not mounted correctly?

Comment: to answer question whether volume is mounted correctly just manually login to the running container and check the dir  ...  docker run only keeps container running for duration of command ... there are other ways to launch a container which depend whether image runs a server or other long running process

Comment: I just checked it and it is present there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for bind mount is:

> -v source_path_in_host:destination_path_in_container

This means for `-v D:/tests/resources:/tmp/output`, the folder in host's `D:/tests/resources` will be mapped into `/tmp/output` in container.

Additional, `prepare --base_path D:/tests/resources` in fact won't be run on host, but will be executed in container. So, for the script `prepare`, it should accept the `--base_path` as `/tmp/output` for command input, not `D:/tests/resources`.